# Nodejs sequelize how to get last insert id

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize with nodejs to insert a row in a table,now i want that last inserted id,i want some thing like "mysql_insert_id()", here is my code:

```
function registerAgent(agent_data,request_key,res,next)
{
  models.agent.create({creator_id: agent_data.userid },  { fields: [ 'creator_id'] }).then(function(user) {
      console.log(user);
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The create() return the last insert element, so the last id is user.id.
Is this for your problem?

```
function registerAgent(agent_data,request_key,res,next)
{
  models.agent.create({creator_id: agent_data.userid },  { fields: [ 'creator_id'] }).then(function(user) {
      console.log(user.id);
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Actually i forgot to add "autoIncrement: true" in my model that's why it was giving null. Thanks its working now :)

Comment: OK, it's my glad to help.